# Redireccionar dominio web en con wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

Hola ¿Cómo están? Necesito de su ayuda. 
Tengo una web hecha con worpress, está presentando problemas al redireccionar la url con WWW.

Si ingreso el nombre del dominio sin el www funciona.

He creado redirecciones 301 desde el cpanel, desde wordpress, he modificado el .htaccess y no logro dar con el error.

Comment: En tu archivo .htaccess intenta poniendo esto: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tudominio.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tudominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]` Reemplaza **tudominio** por el nombre que tengas en tu web. En este enlace encontrás mas información al respecto: [https://www.webempresa.com/blog/codigos-utiles-htaccess-para-sitios-web.html]

Comment: Wordpress siempre intentará redirigirte a la url que tengas configurada en el panel de administración. Si quieres cambiar del apex a www, cambia ese valor en el panel de wordpress en vez de redirigir con apache

Answer (score 0):

has probado utilizando plugins de wordpress, hace tiempo utilice este para redirigir los sitios de un proyecto.

[Redirection](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Espero y te sea de utilidad.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica por favor lo siguiente que en el panel de opciones generales de wordpress
en la dirección del wordpress y dirección del sitio tengas así:

```
https://tusitio.com
```

sin el www

agregar en el .htacces las siguientes lineas así,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tusitio.com/$1 [R,L]
```

luego vas al wp-config.php y agregas las siguientes lineas

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Luego instalas temporalmente alguno de estos dos plugins: Better Search Replace o Database search and replace for WordPress. Haz una búsqueda de http://tusitio.com y reemplaza por https://tusitio.com

Como paso final deber redirigir todo http a https, wordpress lo hace solo pero supone una doble carga, entonces para mejorar el performance de tu sitio incluye estas lineas en tu .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

En este punto al escribir la web con www o sin www no deberias de tener problemas.

Todo esto es suponiendo que tienes tu ssl como todas las web deben tenerlas ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente función de WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/ en tu tema hijo, o en la pagina principal.

```
function redireccionar_pagina(){
   if(is_front_page()){
      wp_redirect( 'CAMBIAR POR URL QUE QUIERES REDIRECCIONAR' );
      exit;
   }
}

add_action('wp','redireccionar_pagina');
```