# ¿ Como redireccionar mi sitio web con la URL con las www?

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, url, redirección

Actualmente misitoweb.es funciona con https://misitoweb.es

También funciona cuando coloco misitoweb.es en la barra del navegador

Pero sin embargo cuando utilizo [www.misitoweb.es](http://www.misitoweb.es) no funciona
El navegador dice lo siguiente:
***Esta página no funciona.
La página [www.misitioweb.es](http://www.misitioweb.es) te ha redirigido demasiadas veces.***

¿ como puedo hacer para que el formato www. tambien me dirija a mi sitio web?

¿ que debo hacer para que todos los formatos me redirijan a https://misitioweb.es?

La URL que tengo en WordPress es https://misitioweb.es
He probado añadiendo un fragmento de código al archivo .htaccess del proyecto, pero no funciona:

```
# Redirigir a la versión sin "www"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.misitioweb\.es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitioweb.es/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Tambien he probado alguna de las propuestas que se ofrecen en Stackoverflow, como la siguiente, pero por algua razón no funciona
[Redireccionar dominio web en con wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197912/redireccionar-dominio-web-en-con-wordpress)

Revisando los consejos de los compañeros, he descubierto que el archivo `.htaccess`no parece que sea correcto. Quiza ahí este el error que me dijo @aloMalbarez en su momento.
¿ Pueden ayudarme a corregirlo ?
Este es el final del archivo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre «BEGIN WordPress» y «END WordPress» son
# generadas dinámicamente y solo deberían ser modificadas mediante filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores serán sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Parecerá bobo pero las direcciones de ejemplo son diferentes... Por otro lado si es WP, en los enlaces permanentes tendrías que poner la configuración deseada y funcionaría bien. Yo he probado unos dominios que tengo y con las `www` redirecciona a `dominio.es`

Comment: fijate si no hay otras reglas que interfieran
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=b442e952-68a0-47e4-ac2c-f105f6ee5d44

Comment: En los enlaces permanentes de WordPress @OCHOA , no se como hacerlo. NO veo nada que hable de `"con wwww"` o que hable de `"sin www"`. ¿ puedes ayudarme con alguna pista. Gracias. Respesto a las reglas que interfieran, nom se como interpretar el archivo .hatccess

Comment: No, no dije que ahí podrías resolverlo, dije que, si tienes una buena config en ese lugar, cuando alguien ponga `www` redirigirá al dominio sin esas `www` y todo debería funcionar bien, porque yo tengo varios dominios con WP que funcionan bien. Creo que lo que dice alo Malbarez puede ayudarte de manera más efectiva...

Comment: `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` es/era un workaround para usar basic auth con mod fastcgi. `AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php` es/era una marca para que los archivos php los maneje el modulo php de apache. que versión de php estas usando? el servidor requiere que uses un user y password ( dialogo del browser ) para acceder? cualquiera de esas dos cosas pueden ser algo heredado y que estén provocando el infinite loop ( fijate que te aparece en https://www.redirect-checker.org/  con tu domain )

Comment: Considera la directiva [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias). Si en la definición de tu *VirtualHost* tienes `ServerName misitioweb.es` tan sólo añade `ServerAlias www.misitioweb.es` y reinicia Apache.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, no me quedo muy claro, no estoy familiarizada con los terminaos de Apache y servidores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no veo la regla que has mencionado anteriormente para redirigir [www.misitioweb.es](http://www.misitioweb.es) a misitioweb.es.

Podrías intentar agregar la siguiente regla en tu archivo .htaccess, justo después de RewriteEngine On:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

y recuerda borrar la cache. Ya me dices

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitioweb.es/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Revisar [answer]